# Java RestHighLevelClient - Elastic Search - How to add special character '/' in id field value

Tags: java, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

Getting exception while inserting field value with '/' in elastic search

Code:

```
String id = "/EACVBSDSFASFA";

IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(INDEX, TYPE, id).source(objectsMap);
                    IndexResponse indexResponse = restHighLevelClient.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Exception:

```
Path part [/EACVBSDSFASFA] couldn't be encoded: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path part [/EACVBSDSFASFA] couldn't be encoded
at org.elasticsearch.client.RequestConverters$EndpointBuilder.encodePart(RequestConverters.java:1142)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RequestConverters$EndpointBuilder.addPathPart(RequestConverters.java:1104)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RequestConverters.endpoint(RequestConverters.java:704)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RequestConverters.index(RequestConverters.java:309)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1761)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1735)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1697)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.index(RestHighLevelClient.java:929)
at 
.....
.....
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in port number at index 30:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not because of the field, but because you're using `/` as part of the id.

I'd guess this is a restriction to prevent resources with where IDs would have to be encoded, e.g. http://localhost:9200/index/_type/%2FEACVBSDSFASFA, note `/` -> `%2F` conversion.

In any case - prefer url-safe IDs, e.g:

- Incremental IDs
- GUIDs
- If you want to use base64 IDs, use base64url version of it - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications where `+`, `=`, `/` are replaced with URI-safe characters.